# Eclipse 2020-09 with JRE11 on Mac is starting 300% CPU java process

Tags: java, eclipse, java-11

I just updated my Eclipse to 2020-09 and installed JRE11 (as this is required now).
Now I always see a java process running, sucking 300% of my CPU for nothing. If i kill it, it reappears after some seconds.
How can I get rid of this unnecessary java process?

Comment: Have you installed additional plugins? Do you see the same with a fresh workspace? Which macOS version do you have?

Comment: macOS 10.15.7, yes I have plugins installed, but i didn't install new plugins, i only updated everything.

Comment: Does the computer slow down, or is this just some sort of internal reporting error? Well, I guess it has to be, because 300% is a bit much. :)

Comment: when I hear the ventilation going up, I know that the java process has been started again. I kill it, and it keeps reappearing all the time. Eclipse itself is running normal, i don't know what kind of java process it is. I uninstalled all plugins, still seeing the process coming

Comment: Sounds a lot like https://bugs.eclipse.org/568668 . See if its workaround works for you.